# Dynamic number of input fields using WTForms

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

is it possible using Flask and WTForms to generate a dynamic amount of input fields?

For example, on a recipe website, when you want to add a recipe I wanted to include multiple Input Fields for the ingredients.
Together with a selector field to determine the number of ingredients x, the site should display x Input fields for the ingredients.

Of course, somehow my backend should recognize them as separate input fields

e.g.:

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
    {{ form.ingred }}
{% endfor %}
```

displays 5 ingredient fields (5 would be variable here ofc), but they share their input data. Is it possible to get their individual data?

Comment: I don't know wforms so I don't know the specific implementation in that, but have you tried sending the data as a comma separated string to the flask endpoint and then spiting it in there?

Comment: I considered this as well, but I'd much rather prefer the method using multiple input fields.

Comment: Then pass an array or dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to build dynamic forms like this is to pre-allocate the form:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    input_1 = ..
    ..
    input_20 = ..
```

But display only some of them using `render_kw` args to configure the style properties or the css class.

Then write Javascript functions on the client side to show specific input fields when the user is interested in adding another item.